# Undefined property: stdClass::$column_name

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am using a script to login (this itself works perfectly) to start a session and transmit the ID of the user who is logged in. In the same way, I want to transmit the "rolle" from my SQL-Table. 
Although the ID works just fine, "rolle" is claimed to be undefined. In my SQL table the column "rolle" is defined and filled.

> **Notice:** Undefined property: stdClass::$rolle in **/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/flensburgpunkte/login.php** on line **35**

```
    if (isset($_GET["login"])) {
          $email = $_POST["email"];
          $passwort = $_POST["passwort"];

          $passwort_hash = password_hash($passwort, PASSWORD_BCRYPT, ['salt' => 'ahsdIOUOASDHuahsjavnsdvuhJNDJASJdhafmvndvjvav732643849']);

          $search_user = $connection->prepare("SELECT id FROM login WHERE email = ? AND passwort = ?");
          $search_user->bind_param('ss',$email,$passwort_hash);
          $search_user->execute();
          $search_result = $search_user->get_result();

          if ($search_result->num_rows == 1) {
            $search_object = $search_result->fetch_object();

            echo $search_object->id."<br>";
            echo $search_object->rolle."<br>";

            $_SESSION['fahrer'] = $search_object->id;
          } else {
            echo "<p style=\"color:#B80C09;\">Deine Angaben waren nicht korrekt.</p><br>";
          }
    }
```

`$search_object->id` works just fine, but `$search_object->rolle` does not work, although it comes from the same row, the id is read from.

Could somebody give me a solution which also provides a result for `$search_object->rolle`?

Comment: Please dont salt `password_hash()` it does a MUCH BETTER JOB all on its own

Comment: If you dont select `rolle` it wont be there to play with

Answer (score 2):

You are not selecting `rolle` you only select `id`

```
SELECT id FROM login WHERE email = ? AND passwort = ?
```

You need to select the columns you want to use so

```
SELECT id,rolle FROM login WHERE email = ? AND passwort = ?
```